# Logic to generate Random Security Questions in mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, random

To find a logic that can randomly pick the question out of 3 questions:

1. If 1st question is answered wrong then just increase the attempt counter
   in database table.
2. Pick the 2nd question randomly, if wrong increase the attempt
   counter in database table.
3. Pick the 3rd question, if wrong increase the attempt in counter
   database table.
4. Again pick a random question in the 3 questions.But it should not be the    previous question that we showed to user. And if wrong increase the attempt counter in database table
5. Again Show the next randomly picked question and increase attempt
   counter in database table

For Example :                                                                    Assume that Q2 is displayed in 1st attempt then the flow would be 
1st Attempt >>  `Q2`
2nd Attempt >> `either Q1/Q3 (Assume Q3)`
3rd Attempt >> `then it would be Q1 for this attempt`
4th Attempt >> `as Q3 was displayed in 2nd attempt,we need to display Q2 now`
5th Attempt >> `either Q3/Q1`

Security questions & answers are pulled from different database through services, hence I will get a List of Class(something like ChallengeQuestion) having it members as Answer,QID,QuestionText.
Will have to incorporate above logic in a MVC project.
I am new to MVC, any Help will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Andrei M, Thanks for replying. I could extract all question set and using Random class's object , could display only 1 question randomly for 1st attempt. Created a model class with QuestionText, QID, Answer and UserID to be passed to view and assigned randomly generated 1st question to it. But got stuck after that :( Any help will be greatly appreciated.